# evaluating summation with counting formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation

I am trying to calculate what $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{T}$$\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{P/2}\binom{i+j}{i}$ is equal to with some effort outside the scope of this article, and I'm having trouble with expressing the right way to do it. Please help

Answer (score 3):

Using the [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity), we have, $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{T}\binom{i+j}{i}=\sum_{i=0}^{T}\binom{i+j}{j}=\binom{j+T+1}{j+1}=\binom{j+T+1}{T}$.

Using the same identity again, we have, $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{T}\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{P}{2}}\binom{i+j}{i}=\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{P}{2}}\binom{j+T+1}{T}=\binom{\frac{P}{2}+T+2}{T+1}-1$ .

Comment: where does the -1 come from?

Comment: Hi, can you please explain where does the trailing 1 comes from?

Comment: @randomvalue That $1$ is actually $\binom{T}{T}$ from the hockey-stick identity.